# getting error when appending array NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I was trying to get the JSON data to an array. Below is the code... I dont know where am I going wrong..

When I keep a Log for arrayJSON Below is the result :

```
Array Result: [{"ID_PROJECT":1,"NM_PROJECT":"TED"},{"ID_PROJECT":2,"NM_PROJECT":"DL"},{"ID_PROJECT":3,"NM_PROJECT":"PERD"},{"ID_PROJECT":4,"NM_PROJECT":"EPRS "},{"ID_PROJECT":5,"NM_PROJECT":"MSCS"}]

NSArray *arrayJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                                                             options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                                               error:&error];

        NSMutableArray *arrayResult = [NSMutableArray array];

        for(NSDictionary *dictJSON in arrayJSON){

            [arrayResult addObject: [dictJSON objectForKey:@"NM_PROJECT"]];
        }

        NSLog(@"Array Result: %@", arrayResult);
```

Here is the error code :

> 014-02-25 15:07:40.602 Demologin[1146:c07] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[__NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x715f430'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x1ca3012 0x114fe7e 0x1d2e4bd 0x1c92bbc 0x1c9294e 0xad28 0x1061c7 0x106232 0x553d5 0x5576f 0x55905 0x5e917
>   0x2296c 0x2394b 0x34cb5 0x35beb 0x27698 0x1bfedf9 0x1bfead0 0x1c18bf5
>   0x1c18962 0x1c49bb6 0x1c48f44 0x1c48e1b 0x2317a 0x24ffc 0x26ad 0x25d5)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: `NSLog` the `arrayJSON` and check what type it is

Comment: It is like Array Result: [{"ID_PROJECT":1,"NM_PROJECT":"DL"},{"ID_PROJECT":2,"NM_PROJECT":"PSM System"},{"ID_PROJECT":3,"NM_PROJECT":"ETR "},{"ID_PROJECT":4,"NM_PROJECT":"SMS"},{"ID_PROJECT":5,"NM_PROJECT":"Companies Information Database"},{"ID_PROJECT":6,"NM_PROJECT":"New Project"}]

Comment: Martin Ur AWESOME.. You made my life easy.. Thank you. I was very new to IOS.. SO I was a bit confused. Thanks Man.. Cheers..

Answer (score 1):

```
Array Result: [{"ID_PROJECT":1,"NM_PROJECT":"TED"},{"ID_PROJECT":2,"NM_PROJECT":"DL"},{"ID_PROJECT":3,"NM_PROJECT":"PERD"},{"ID_PROJECT":4,"NM_PROJECT":"EPRS "},{"ID_PROJECT":5,"NM_PROJECT":"MSCS"}]

NSMutableArray *array = [Array Result JSONValue];
[array retain];


NSLog(@"Array Result: %@", array);
```

Comment: I am Not using SBJSON or so Bhavesh.. Thank you for the quick rsponse